# netlogo lists: iterating over two lists

Tags: list, netlogo

I have two lists, both will always be the same length.  The first is binary and says whether an agent will move this round, the second contains a set of agents that will need to do something, based on the first list.  Something like:

```
list1 = [0 1 1 1 0]
list2 = [turtle-1 turtle-2 turtle-55 turtle-6 turtle-8]
```

My objective is to create a third list with only the active turtles in it.  Accordingly this list will comprise: turtle-2 turtle-55 and turtle-6.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: There are languages where it is natural to treat agent attributes as lists, but NetLogo is not one of them.  Unless you are doing this for some performance-related reason, you will probably want to declare say `turtles-own [active]` and set this attribute appropriate to `true` or `false` using the same logic that produces your `list1`.  The turtleset of active turtles is then just `turtles with [active]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
map last filter [first ? = 1] (map list list1 list2)
```

sample run:

```
observer> crt 10
observer> set list1 [0 1 1 1 0]
observer> set list2 map turtle [1 2 5 6 8]
observer> show map last filter [first ? = 1] (map list list1 list2)
observer: [(turtle 2) (turtle 5) (turtle 6)]
```

Comment: Thanks @Seth Tisue for using Map. I didn't remember how to use it.

Comment: Thanks to both Seth and Marzy

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you can do it with map (Map is cleaner and more efficient) but with foreach you can do it as follow :

```
to test-lists
  let list3 []
  foreach list2 [ 
    if (item (position ? list2) list1  = 1)[
      set list3 lput ? list3
    ]
  ]

  print (word "List1 is " list1)
  print (word "List2 is " list2)
  print (word "List3 is " list3)
end
```

This is the output:

```
List1 is [0 1 1 1 0]
List2 is [(turtle 1) (turtle 2) (turtle 55) (turtle 6) (turtle 8)]
List3 is [(turtle 2) (turtle 55) (turtle 6)]
```